# How to traverse all nodes of a Directed Acyclic Graph in a specific order?

Tags: graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a problem where I need to traverse ALL nodes of the Directed Acyclic graph in a specific order because some nodes/vertices are dependent on results of multiple other nodes/vertices.

In this case, DFS or BFS won't work.

What is the solution/algorithm/ threads for traversing a DAG like this?

Should I be also ordering the nodes? eg: That node which does not depend on anything else - is first, then Node A, then Node B, then C (which depends on Node A and Node B).. beforehand?

Comment: We would have to know what specific order you're talking about, but if some nodes are dependent on others, that suggests you might be looking for a topological sorting of nodes.

Comment: More information is needed, like what is the nature of the dependency of B in A, and more important is that dependency know before traversing. Consider [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was topological sort which can be implemented using

- Kahn's algorithm
- Depth-first search or
- Parallel algorithms

Thanks @beaker